# Does a view controller get removed entirely when using a custom transition?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers. On the first one I have a button, which shows the second one modally. Then, I close the second one by tapping a button on it (it goes down). For dismissing transition I have created a custom class which conforms to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, so I use a custom transition animation for view controllers (I needed a custom behaviour during the dismissing  transition).

My question is the following: because of a custom transition that I use, is my view controller still get removed after the transition finishes or is it still there but off the screen? And if it is, will it affect the memory and how bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said:

> is my view controller still get removed after the transition finishes or is it still there but off the screen?

There are two completely separate issues here.

First, there is a question of the view controller hierarchy. When you present a new view controller, the old view controller is always kept in the view controller hierarchy so that when you dismiss back to it, it will still be there. However, when you dismiss, the dismissed view controller will be removed from the view controller hierarchy and (unless you do something unusual, like keeping your own strong reference to it somewhere) it will be deallocated.

Second, there is a separate question of the view hierarchy. When presenting, the `UIPresentationController` dictates whether the presenting view controller's view remains in the view hierarchy or not. By default, it keeps it in the view hierarchy, but generally if doing a modal, full-screen "present", you'd specify a `UIPresentationController` subclass that tells it to remove the presenting view controller's view when the transition is done.

---

For example, when doing a custom modal "present" transition where the presented view controller's view is opaque and covers the whole screen, then your `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` would not only supply the animation controllers, but also specify a presentation controller:

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return YourAnimationController(...)
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return YourAnimationController(...)
}

func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return PresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
}
```

And that presentation controller might be fairly minimal, only telling it to remove the presenter's view:

```
class PresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    override var shouldRemovePresentersView: Bool { return true }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. The method `presentationController(forPresented:presenting:source)` is called when presenting a new `view controller`, right? So, what if I still use a default modal segue animation for presenting a new `view controller` and I use a custom one for dismissing it?

Comment: I'd guess that it would be removed (because the default modal presentation always removes the presenter's view from the view hierarchy), but it might check to see what your presentation controller does. I'd suggest you just use the Xcode view debugger and confirm. Personally, I would always implement my own presentation animation if doing my own dismissing animation. You'd hate to see some future iOS version change the presenting animation in some way that breaks your app.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice. I'll create a custom presentation animation, too. About  the presenter's view: if a modal segue's `presentationStyle` is set to `overCurrentContext` (or `overFullScreen`), the view will still be there, right? I remember, I've met that kind of behaviour (the presenter's view was still visible in the Xcode view debugger). Is that a normal behaviour for that kind of `presentationStyle`?

Comment: [The documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate) that, "When you want to present a view controller using a custom modal presentation type, set its `modalPresentationStyle` property to `custom` and assign an object that conforms to this protocol to its `transitioningDelegate` property." As the docs say to use `custom`, I haven't experimented with other `modalPresentationStyle` settings (and not sure I'd suggest doing that).

Comment: Ok, Rob. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewController` remains in the hierarchy.

You can confirm this by verifying the value of `self.parentViewController` property in the modal view controller.

**Edit:**

> Will that view controller affect the memory?

Yes it will continue to perform all operations or activities (e.g: streaming audio, playing animation, running timers etc) in the parentViewController.

> And if so, how can this situation be handled?

There are methods available in UIViewController class to detect when a ViewController will or is appeared / disappeared.
More specifically, following methods are at your disposal:

1. [viewWillAppear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear) (Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy)
2. [viewDidAppear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear) (Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy)
3. [viewWillDisappear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear) (Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be removed from a view hierarchy)
4. [viewDidDisappear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear) (Notifies the view controller that its view was removed from a view hierarchy)

You can use `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` in `parentViewController` to start or resume such activities / operations.
And `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` to suspend or stop such activities / operations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just tested it now on my project and in my case it was nil even before calling `completeTransition` (presented using `present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`).. any idea what up with it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, will that `view controller` affect the memory (I think it will)? And if so, how can this situation be handled?

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm going assume that you are speaking about the `view` of your modal `viewController` staying in the window hierarchy - since you are asking if it is still there but off the screen, I believe you are talking about the view, and the controller, since controller is never on the screen.

And if you are asking about the `view` (which I assume that you are), calling `completeTransition` on `transitionContext` will remove it from the window hierarchy (so there is no need to call `fromVC.view.removeFromSuperview()`) - and by contract you are required to call `completeTransition` when the transition finishes in the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` implementation.

You can confirm this behavior by checking the value of `fromVC.view.superview` before and after calling `transitionContext.completeTransition`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
    fromVC.view.frame = endFrame
}) { (_) in
    print(">>> \(fromVC.view.superview)")
    transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    print(">>> \(fromVC.view.superview)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the previous UIViewController remains there.
As described in [**Apple docs**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)

> viewControllerToPresent
>   The view controller to display over the
>   current view controller’s content.

Comment: So, this behaviour happens when I use a custom transition or it always happens when modal segues are used?

Comment: ViewController - remains in hierarchy. View - As Rob mentioned, it provides with the option to remove the presenter's view from hierarchy.